# Why is Dense network outperforming LSTM on regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, lstm, keras

I'm working on PV system power output forecast, this is my dataset:

[image: Solar power dataset]

3 years of data with 15 min temporal resolution.

I then cut this into `x_train, y_train, x_test` and `y_test` using this class:

```
class Timeseries_to_supervised():
    def __init__(self, df, train_test_split, input_length, target_size, remove_na = False, step_size = 1):
        self.df = df
        self.step_size = step_size
        
        if isinstance(self.df, pd.DataFrame) != True:
            print('df should be a pandas dataframe (rows, columns) = (pandas.datetimeindex, features) where the first feature is the target variable')
        
        train_test_index = len(self.df.loc[:train_test_split])-target_size
                
        self.x_train, self.y_train = self.multivariate_data(0, train_test_index-1, input_length, target_size)
        self.x_test, self.y_test = self.multivariate_data(train_test_index+1, None, input_length, target_size)
        
        if remove_na:
            self.x_train, self.y_train = self.remove_nan(self.x_train, self.y_train)
            self.x_test, self.y_test = self.remove_nan(self.x_test, self.y_test)
          
    def multivariate_data(self, start_index, end_index, history_size, target_size,
                          remove_na = True, target = 0, step = 60, single_step=False):
        
        df = self.df.values
        
        target = df[:,target]
        data = []
        labels = []
        start_index = start_index + history_size
        
        if end_index is None:
            end_index = len(df) - target_size

        for i in range(start_index, end_index, self.step_size):
            indices = range(i-history_size, i)
            data.append(df[indices])

            if single_step:
                labels.append(target[i+target_size])
            else:
                labels.append(target[i:i+target_size])
            
        return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
    
    def remove_nan(self, X, Y):
        x = []
        y = []
        for sample in range(X.shape[0]):
            if np.isnan(X[sample,:,:]).any() | np.isnan(Y[sample,:]).any():
                None
            else:
                x.append(X[sample,:,:])
                y.append(Y[sample,:])
        x = np.array(x)
        y = np.array(y)
        return x, y
```

Since my dataset contains many missing values spread evenly throughout the three years I decided to remove any samples that contain even a single missing value.

**My question is as follows:** If i train a `Sequential` keras model using a `LSTM` layer followed by a Dense layer its forecasting accuracy (1 step ahead) is markedly worse than using just the Dense layer at the end. And I can't figure out why. Please help me understand :)

LSTM model:

```
Model: "sequential_193"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_166 (LSTM)              (None, 70)                20160     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_391 (Dense)            (None, 100)               7100      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_189 (Dropout)        (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_392 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 27,361
Trainable params: 27,361
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 4838 samples, validate on 4838 samples
Epoch 1/50
4838/4838 - 3s - loss: 0.0114 - val_loss: 0.0108
Epoch 2/50
4838/4838 - 2s - loss: 0.0091 - val_loss: 0.0098
.
.
.
Epoch 27/50
4838/4838 - 2s - loss: 0.0078 - val_loss: 0.0081
-------------------------------- (early stopping)
```

[image: LSTM model history]

Dense model:

```
Model: "sequential_195"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_37 (Flatten)         (None, 180)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_395 (Dense)            (None, 100)               18100     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_191 (Dropout)        (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_396 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 18,201
Trainable params: 18,201
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 4838 samples, validate on 4838 samples
Epoch 1/50
4838/4838 - 1s - loss: 0.0378 - val_loss: 0.0153
Epoch 2/50
4838/4838 - 0s - loss: 0.0147 - val_loss: 0.0147
.
.
.
4838/4838 - 0s - loss: 0.0049 - val_loss: 0.0038
Epoch 35/50
4838/4838 - 0s - loss: 0.0047 - val_loss: 0.0045
Epoch 36/50
4838/4838 - 0s - loss: 0.0047 - val_loss: 0.0045
Epoch 37/50
4838/4838 - 0s - loss: 0.0046 - val_loss: 0.0043
Epoch 38/50
4838/4838 - 0s - loss: 0.0044 - val_loss: 0.0041
Epoch 39/50
4838/4838 - 0s - loss: 0.0043 - val_loss: 0.0040
-------------------------------- (early stopping)
```

[image: Dense model history]

This is the code I used to generate my models, I change the variables: "self.CONV_POOL_LAYERS" to 0 for the LSTM net shown in this post, and I change "self.LSTM_LAYERS" to 0 too for the Dense net in this post:

```
self.INPUT_LENGTH      = 180
self.FILTERS           = 64
self.KERNEL_SIZE       = 2
self.PADDING           = 'same'
self.ACTIVATION        = 'relu'
self.CONV_LAYERS       = 1
self.POOL_SIZE         = 2
self.MAX_POOLING       = False
self.CONV_POOL_LAYERS  = 1
self.LSTM_LAYERS       = 1
self.LSTM_UNITS        = 70
self.DENSE_LAYERS      = 1
self.DROPOUT           = 0.2
self.DENSE_UNITS       = 100
self.LOSS              = 'mse'
self.LEARNING_RATE     = 0.0005
self.EPOCHS            = 50
self.BATCH_SIZE        = 24

self.initializer = keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0., stddev=0.05)
self.bias = keras.initializers.Constant(0.1) 
self.lstm_bias_initializer = keras.initializers.Constant(value=0.1)

self.training_verbosity = 0
self.min_training_samples = 100
self.early_stopping_patience = 5

def make_model(self, print_summary = True):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(keras.Input(shape = (self.x_train.shape[1], self.x_train.shape[2])))
                
        for i in range(self.CONV_POOL_LAYERS):
            for i in range(self.CONV_LAYERS):
                model.add(Conv1D(filters            = self.FILTERS,
                                 kernel_size        = self.KERNEL_SIZE,
                                 padding            = self.PADDING,
                                 activation         = self.ACTIVATION))
            
            if self.MAX_POOLING == True: model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = self.POOL_SIZE))
        
        for i in range(self.LSTM_LAYERS):
            model.add(LSTM(units = self.LSTM_UNITS, 
                           return_sequences = False))
            
            #model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
            #model.add(Activation(self.ACTIVATION))
        
        model.add(Flatten())
        for i in range(self.DENSE_LAYERS):
            model.add(Dense(units              = self.DENSE_UNITS, 
                            activation         = self.ACTIVATION))

        
        model.add(Dropout(rate = self.DROPOUT))
        model.add(Dense(units               = self.y_train.shape[1], 
                        activation          = self.ACTIVATION))
        
        
        model.compile(loss = self.LOSS, optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.LEARNING_RATE))
        
        if print_summary: model.summary()
        
        self.model = model
        return model
        
    def fit_model(self, plot = True, save_best_model = True, early_stopping = True, tensorboard = False):
        
        tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = '/logs')
        
        model_path = self.results_path + self.model_name + '.h5'
        if self.x_train.shape[0] > self.min_training_samples:
            
            self.history = self.model.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train,
                                        epochs          = self.EPOCHS, 
                                        batch_size      = self.BATCH_SIZE,
                                        validation_data = (self.x_test, self.y_test),
                                        callbacks       = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience = self.early_stopping_patience),
                                                           keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath = model_path, 
                                                                                           save_best_only = True, 
                                                                                           monitor = 'val_loss'),
                                                          ],
                                        verbose         = self.training_verbosity,
                                        shuffle         = False)
            self.model = load_model(model_path)
```

Normally, I wouldn't post so much in a single post, but I'm stumped, everything I read led me to believe that the LSTM layer should be doing the heavy lifting, but its not. If i forecast 10 or 50 steps into the future the Dense layer still wins out. I must be doing something wrong, but what?

To make things worse, I have about 52 features on top of the PV data. When I compare multivariate `LSTM` nets with my univariate Dense net, the Dense net still ends up winning.

Comment: Have you tried using different early stopping settings? On the plot, it looks like LSTM at the 25th epoch is in a similar place as the Dense model, so question is, what would happen if you trained longer?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read my whole post and help me look for a resolution! I have tried training it for longer, many times in fact. But the results described above are highly repeatable I'm afraid. One thing to note is that the y axis scale for the mse V epoch plot is different for both models, so they look more similar than they are in reality.